# What happens when the battery on my Apple Watch dies while I'm working out?

Tags: battery, apple-watch

The battery died while I was using Workout.app on my Apple Watch. What happens to my workout data when my watch finishes charging?

Comment: Shouldn’t you be able to find out as soon as the watch os boots in 5 or 10 minutes?

Comment: No data will be recorded once the battery has died, but data recorded prior to loss of power may be - that will depend on how the watch and the app handle a suspend command or it just dies...

Answer (score 5):

You lose everything that it had. Just happened to me.